# Twilio - How to get media url from messages list?

Tags: twilio, mms, twilio-php

I am using this code to get the list of messages received. I like to get the media url of the image if the message is a MMS message. I can identify the MMS with num_media property.

I don't know how to the get media url. The document says about subresource_uris. I am not sure how to use this in this case.

```
  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken); 

  $messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 5, array()) ;
  $media = "";
  foreach($messages as $sms) {

      if ($sms->num_media > 0)
      {

      }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The media attached to a message can be found by querying the [Media list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) for that message. That's nice and easy in the PHP library as you need to loop over the `media` resource for the `$sms` message. Like so:

```
  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken); 

  $messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 5, array()) ;
  $media = "";
  foreach($messages as $sms) {

      if ($sms->num_media > 0)
      {
          foreach($sms->media as $media) {
            echo $media->uri;
          }
      }


  }
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: When I do this, the URI returned is a json file. How do I get the actual image sent?

Comment: The `Uri` field of the JSON that’s returned is where you’ll find the image itself.

Comment: I think I see the problem...the media I was testing on was older. Not sure if Twilio eventually deletes it or if it was maybe just a bad file when I sent initially. But it wasn't able to find the file. It seems to be working on more recent media.

Comment: Twilio shouldn’t delete things unless you choose for them to be deleted. Glad you’ve figured it out though.

Comment: Im having an issue with this, when I send a request to the uri, it returns the same JSON object, with a Uri. Issue is when I get request this Uri, it just keep returning a json object, I get the json object uri, get request on it, same result. shouldnt I be getting a blob or something to put in an img tag? <img> tag with src={`https://api.twilio./2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc3777174/Messages/MMdf439bd7ea83404c/Media/ME198b5b06be57d.json`}

Comment: @ErikaPeterson007 remove the `.json` from the URI.